# Second person singluar imperative of a reflexive verb ending in a diphthong

Tags: verbos, reflexivos, tiempos-verbales

The question is pretty much in the title.  If I have the verb lavarse, I know to make the imperative I use lávate.

But what to do with a verb like afeitarse?  Is it afeitate? My spellcheck thinks not.  But then where should the accent go?

Comment: Where is the diphtong in that verbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spain we say "aféitate", but in places where voseo is used they say "afeitate" (stress in the second "a", but <strike>I'm not sure if it has graphical accent</strike> without written accent).

Comment: "afeitate" with the stree on the secon a can't have an accent mark according to the ortographic rules.

Comment: I know, but I'm not sure how they are applied in places where voseo is used, or if there any exception for those cases. Check [this link](http://www.elplog.com/2010/04/28/joven-argentino-busca-trabajo%E2%80%A6/). It's full of afeitáte, bañáte, cambiáte... But I'm not sure about its correctness, since there are some other which must have an accent, that don't have it...

Comment: Ok, just [checked the DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ#43), and it's clear it must not have a written accent. Prior to 1999, apparently, it did. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think we should stick to a simple answer. Posting exceptions (e.g. voseo) is very confusing for learners. The answer is simple: lavarse->lávate; afeitarse->aféitate.

Comment: @Pablo: It's not so simple, in my opinion. There are places where `lavarse -> lávate` is not the rule, but rather `lavarse -> lavate`.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.  I didn't even know about voseo until now, so thanks for that too!

Comment: @MikMik I know, but the question was: For the imperative I use "lávate" for lavarse. How is it with afeitarse? The answer is simply "aféitate". And that's the standard Spanish rule. The other information is interesting but extra, and it's confusing for newbies.